# File Abstraction Layer StorageIndexer scheduler task fails

Tags: typo3, fal

I have a TYPO3 project where my customer uploads files to a directory inside the /fileadmin folder via ftp. I've tried to create a scheduler task to update the StorageIndex, but it doesn't work. The scheduler task stops running and is marked as failed. No log entry is written.

[image]

The Scheduler is started by a cronjob, which, based on execution times in other tasks, does work properly.

When I run the cli_dispatch.phpsh scheduler manually from the command line, no output is generated. How can I find out, whats the problem here?

Comment: You can hover over red marked Error tag, it will show details for this error.

Comment: Oh wow - that's unintuitive. "Ausführung fehlgeschlagen: 1314085990, Desired storage "" is not in the list of available storages.". Well. There are two deleted storages in this system. I'll try to reactivate them and start the job over.

Comment: Yup, that helped. Thanks so much.